# Executing 64-bit process from 32-bit process with fork() + execv()

Tags: macos, process

Can `fork()` + `execv()` functions be used to execute 64-bit process from 32-bit process? `fork()` + `execv()` duplicates the process and replaces its image, and trying to replace a 32-bit process image with 64-bit image might be not so good idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem replacing a 32-bit process with a 64-bit image using `execv` (or any of its kin). It replaces the entire image. This is fine and normal.